# Django view os.system permissions / post-receive hook

Tags: django, github, hook

I have an executable bash script called "pullhook" on my PATH that pulls some repos and runs `collectstatic`. It updates the site just fine when I run it in bash or in a Python shell:

```
import os
os.system('pullhook')
```

I made a view that runs the code above and return an HttpReponse and set that to a URL, so I could make it my Github post-receive hook url. But I think I'm doing this wrong. Visiting the URL doesn't update the site as it should.

For testing purposes right now the executable has full permissions:

`-rwxrwxrwx pullhook*`

Can someone guide me in the right direction of how to set up a post-receive hook URL with Django?

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition with file permissions is good, but there are lots of other system level things that could be going wrong.  Environment variables, PATH, etc.  I'd modify your pullhook script to log to a well known file.  First verify that it's running at all, and logging with

```
echo "pullhook running" >> /home/youruser/pullhook.log
```

and similarly redirect all necessary debugging output into the `pullhook.log` file.